# JSON Stringify function returns equal but chai's equal function returns not equal

Tags: json, node.js, chai

In a test suite using chai 'should' asserts, the following returns false:

```
some.json.blob.should.equal(some.other.json.blob);
```

However, this returns true:

```
JSON.stringify(some.json.blob).should.equal(JSON.stringify(some.other.json.blob));
```

I know that the stringify() function is not the most robust way to test for JSON equivalence, so I want to find a way to compare the JSON directly without going through stringify. How can I compare the objects directly without using JSON.stringify()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare JSON without using JSON.stringify, use a deep equal with your chai assertion:

```
some.json.blob.should.deep.equal(some.other.json.blob);
```

See [Chai's documentation](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) for more details on `deep.equal`.

Comment: Why do you answer your own question that quickly? And yes deepEqual is correct.

Comment: I didn't see the question answered anywhere on stackOverflow, so I posted the answer here in case I need to look it up later / with the hope that others will benefit from it. Thanks!